Low Latency Communication in C++: Raw Sockets with io_uring vs. ZeroMQ, NanoMQ, Aeron etc
I have two C++ services that need ultra low-latency communication over the network. I'm considering using raw sockets with io_uring but also looking at possibilities of using various messaging queues like ZeroMQ, NanoMQ, and Aeron UDP etc.
My Questions:

How does the latency and performance of raw sockets with io_uring compare to ZeroMQ, NanoMQ, and Aeron UDP?
Is the added complexity of raw sockets with io_uring worth it compared to the simplicity of high-level libraries?
Can you provide sample code examples for implementing raw sockets with io_uring?

some code example so far i found is just this : https://unixism.net/loti/tutorial/webserver_liburing.html
but its http server and client, i probably dont need to have http as application protocol.
Any insights or benchmarks would be appreciated. Thanks!

You're already going over the network. A handful of nanoseconds in kernelspace will not make the difference. And if it did you would not be using the kernel TCP/IP stack. Regardless, way too broad to answer succinctly beyond "keep it simple".

ZeroMQ has nothing to do with low-latency comms. You're comparing apples and oranges. With that said, if nanosecond latency is of importance, just use native sockets and an epoll loop, no threads.

Aeron has been focused on low-latency and high-throughput from its inception. It is typically orders of magnitude better performance than other messaging technologies. Aeron typically adds only 1-2 microseconds to the RTT of raw transports such as sockets. Aeron can achieve even lower latency with kernel bypass extensions as a premium offering such as DPDK for cloud, ef_vi for Solarflare, and VMA Express for Mellanox network cards. The same API can be used to cover UDP multicast, UDP unicast, and IPC over shared memory. Unlike other UDP messaging, Aeron is reliable with built-in flow and congestion control.
